# Issues deploying MERN app to Heroku. Front end appears for a brief moment before disappearing and issues connecting to back end

Tags: javascript, node.js, heroku, react-router, mern

Link to my project: https://bloglazaustin.herokuapp.com/
Link to the GitHub: https://github.com/LazAustin/Blog.git

No matter what I do, I cannot get this to deploy properly. It works just fine on my local server. Currently, the front end/client is nested within the backend/api folder. I've read numerous similar posts on here and Google. The IP is whitelisted. I've tried proxies in the package.json. I've tried a Procfile. I've tried manually writing the routes in the index.js. I've changed up the folder structure. I've tried numerous start/build/postbuild scripts. I have a feeling its something simple that someone more experienced could catch in a quick glance. I've spent a lot of time on this and another project I need to deploy and am so close to moving on to something else for a while if I can just deploy it.

Error from Chrome Dev console: `Uncaught TypeError: n.map is not a function`
Heroku logs --tail:

```
2022-07-26T23:51:26.347772+00:00 app[web.1]: [nodemon] watching extensions: js,mjs,json
2022-07-26T23:51:26.348077+00:00 app[web.1]: [nodemon] starting `node index.js`
2022-07-26T23:51:26.721443+00:00 app[web.1]: Connected to MongoDB
2022-07-26T23:51:26.724031+00:00 app[web.1]: Backend is running.
2022-07-26T23:51:26.874197+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to up
2022-07-26T23:51:32.855339+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/" host=bloglazaustin.herokuapp.com request_id=85bff5b3-51b9-419a-8caa-6909957b8dd7 fwd="75.66.230.101" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=11ms status=200 bytes=1388 protocol=https
2022-07-26T23:51:32.979054+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/static/js/main.c018063c.js" host=bloglazaustin.herokuapp.com request_id=7de43fd8-7051-4fc8-95a1-7353c9cac2ed fwd="75.66.230.101" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=4ms status=200 bytes=204076 protocol=https
2022-07-26T23:51:32.980767+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/static/css/main.8101a4de.css" host=bloglazaustin.herokuapp.com request_id=1eb36efe-bec3-41a6-9bd3-6a3be0d8c77d fwd="75.66.230.101" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=1ms status=200 bytes=15628 protocol=https
2022-07-26T23:51:33.333000+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/static/media/lazPng1.90669477e0ea598ca37d.png" host=bloglazaustin.herokuapp.com request_id=b86b5884-2b53-4458-84e1-dacb5ea1ae92 fwd="75.66.230.101" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=6ms status=200 bytes=212690 protocol=https
2022-07-26T23:51:33.337084+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/static/media/lazProf.77a7e469645a5f9fb12b.jpg" host=bloglazaustin.herokuapp.com request_id=73a06526-aaae-40e0-b901-2cbcb32573df fwd="75.66.230.101" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=10ms status=200 bytes=1142755 protocol=https
2022-07-26T23:51:33.487544+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/categories" host=bloglazaustin.herokuapp.com request_id=fff4605e-6a59-4257-921f-dda8025837ba fwd="75.66.230.101" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=2ms status=200 bytes=1388 protocol=https  
2022-07-26T23:51:33.499882+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=bloglazaustin.herokuapp.com request_id=e2b14ad6-e52d-4d2a-98a1-3c73ed88a5c6 fwd="75.66.230.101" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=2ms status=200 bytes=1388 protocol=https 
2022-07-26T23:51:33.500355+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/posts" host=bloglazaustin.herokuapp.com request_id=d1bbbae9-3a97-422c-be36-afccaa875350 fwd="75.66.230.101" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=2ms status=200 bytes=1388 protocol=https       
2022-07-26T23:51:33.541505+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/categories" host=bloglazaustin.herokuapp.com request_id=df016136-0776-404b-b440-4993afd4e9ea fwd="75.66.230.101" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=1ms status=304 bytes=269 protocol=https   
2022-07-26T23:51:33.556044+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/manifest.json" host=bloglazaustin.herokuapp.com request_id=0cecd020-148b-46aa-aad3-2479fa4b74fd fwd="75.66.230.101" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=1ms status=200 bytes=373 protocol=https2022-07-26T23:54:24.226300+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/" host=bloglazaustin.herokuapp.com request_id=b0b57569-4991-40fb-b95d-6ae0d3dfd54d fwd="75.66.230.101" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=2ms status=304 bytes=269 protocol=https
2022-07-26T23:54:24.355785+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/static/js/main.c018063c.js" host=bloglazaustin.herokuapp.com request_id=00212db6-4119-4be1-8dfb-1cffa02b4155 fwd="75.66.230.101" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=1ms status=304 bytes=271 protocol=https
2022-07-26T23:54:24.358239+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/static/css/main.8101a4de.css" host=bloglazaustin.herokuapp.com request_id=22fde4a5-4cfc-4d7e-88de-740d555b6dad fwd="75.66.230.101" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=2ms status=304 bytes=270 protocol=https
2022-07-26T23:54:24.515798+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/static/media/lazPng1.90669477e0ea598ca37d.png" host=bloglazaustin.herokuapp.com request_id=b0116254-4054-4423-91bd-3d1b00453beb fwd="75.66.230.101" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=1ms status=304 bytes=271 protocol=https
2022-07-26T23:54:24.522405+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/static/media/lazProf.77a7e469645a5f9fb12b.jpg" host=bloglazaustin.herokuapp.com request_id=eb57fe5c-a58f-48d8-aecc-d1db641ffed5 fwd="75.66.230.101" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=1ms status=304 bytes=272 protocol=https
2022-07-26T23:54:24.587232+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/posts" host=bloglazaustin.herokuapp.com request_id=28dc1be1-6027-40fa-be69-a803f3f72ba0 fwd="75.66.230.101" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=2ms status=304 bytes=269 protocol=https        
2022-07-26T23:54:24.588116+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/categories" host=bloglazaustin.herokuapp.com request_id=ed65f969-ac90-4234-85ad-40f1febcfdea fwd="75.66.230.101" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=2ms status=304 bytes=269 protocol=https   
2022-07-26T23:54:24.683449+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/categories" host=bloglazaustin.herokuapp.com request_id=5a71062e-e300-4257-8191-ae48d8caa564 fwd="75.66.230.101" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=2ms status=304 bytes=269 protocol=https
2022-07-26T23:54:24.684596+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=bloglazaustin.herokuapp.com request_id=c0fdf8f5-8b1f-4e0f-bc39-c46639d4e35d fwd="75.66.230.101" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=1ms status=304 bytes=269 protocol=https  
2022-07-26T23:54:24.805394+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/manifest.json" host=bloglazaustin.herokuapp.com request_id=a089f91d-7813-4da4-905d-6f0340c86bdb fwd="75.66.230.101" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=1ms status=304 bytes=268 protocol=https2022-07-26T23:54:28.922045+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/" host=bloglazaustin.herokuapp.com request_id=ac72fb82-9693-47fe-b69e-f526c880d592 fwd="75.66.230.101" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=1ms status=304 bytes=269 protocol=https
2022-07-26T23:54:29.038712+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/static/js/main.c018063c.js" host=bloglazaustin.herokuapp.com request_id=88e91222-53df-4e4e-b18b-0e28567efaec fwd="75.66.230.101" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=1ms status=304 bytes=271 protocol=https
2022-07-26T23:54:29.039433+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/static/css/main.8101a4de.css" host=bloglazaustin.herokuapp.com request_id=cef5c084-2903-4bd7-b2e0-be8aff373197 fwd="75.66.230.101" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=0ms status=304 bytes=270 protocol=https
2022-07-26T23:54:29.154385+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/static/media/lazPng1.90669477e0ea598ca37d.png" host=bloglazaustin.herokuapp.com request_id=3a690d19-d923-4d9a-b152-d55f00735139 fwd="75.66.230.101" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=1ms status=304 bytes=271 protocol=https
2022-07-26T23:54:29.166247+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/static/media/lazProf.77a7e469645a5f9fb12b.jpg" host=bloglazaustin.herokuapp.com request_id=ba69258d-23d7-47ba-881d-db6531237d44 fwd="75.66.230.101" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=1ms status=304 bytes=272 protocol=https
2022-07-26T23:54:29.177703+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/categories" host=bloglazaustin.herokuapp.com request_id=632a24ac-d317-4e70-98d3-ab4931c412a1 fwd="75.66.230.101" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=1ms status=304 bytes=269 protocol=https   
2022-07-26T23:54:29.180391+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/posts" host=bloglazaustin.herokuapp.com request_id=86df1192-e0cf-4e92-af41-6261342dde40 fwd="75.66.230.101" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=1ms status=304 bytes=269 protocol=https        
2022-07-26T23:54:29.223391+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/manifest.json" host=bloglazaustin.herokuapp.com request_id=c468e6a9-7760-4ef3-a28b-142c1640e6c3 fwd="75.66.230.101" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=1ms status=304 bytes=268 protocol=https2022-07-26T23:54:29.231065+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=bloglazaustin.herokuapp.com request_id=275a48cd-4dc4-4fe1-8cff-7dde8ad94745 fwd="75.66.230.101" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=2ms status=304 bytes=269 protocol=https
2022-07-26T23:54:29.254962+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/categories" host=bloglazaustin.herokuapp.com request_id=bb318b50-82cb-4758-a47f-ae59442dc56e fwd="75.66.230.101" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=1ms status=304 bytes=269 protocol=https   
2022-07-26T23:54:30.332898+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/" host=bloglazaustin.herokuapp.com request_id=07f644d1-9f36-4592-88a5-4385b3e0889d fwd="75.66.230.101" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=1ms status=304 bytes=269 protocol=https
2022-07-26T23:54:30.441011+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/static/js/main.c018063c.js" host=bloglazaustin.herokuapp.com request_id=d98d4ad9-fcc7-4754-b37e-2e776678825b fwd="75.66.230.101" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=1ms status=304 bytes=271 protocol=https
2022-07-26T23:54:30.449027+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/static/css/main.8101a4de.css" host=bloglazaustin.herokuapp.com request_id=e0a74836-f518-451d-80aa-d4d5de8de72a fwd="75.66.230.101" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=1ms status=304 bytes=270 protocol=https
2022-07-26T23:54:30.515494+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/static/media/lazPng1.90669477e0ea598ca37d.png" host=bloglazaustin.herokuapp.com request_id=ac7a885e-ae81-480c-a6dc-9c4417d40c57 fwd="75.66.230.101" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=1ms status=304 bytes=271 protocol=https
2022-07-26T23:54:30.523391+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/static/media/lazProf.77a7e469645a5f9fb12b.jpg" host=bloglazaustin.herokuapp.com request_id=666ad1a3-18fb-48bb-bcbe-a830bea1f4c1 fwd="75.66.230.101" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=1ms status=304 bytes=272 protocol=https
2022-07-26T23:54:30.538239+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/categories" host=bloglazaustin.herokuapp.com request_id=53385fc4-343e-40ce-a65a-057b789243ce fwd="75.66.230.101" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=1ms status=304 bytes=269 protocol=https   
2022-07-26T23:54:30.541643+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/posts" host=bloglazaustin.herokuapp.com request_id=c68bc609-26a0-41fb-ac5c-defd2ccba75e fwd="75.66.230.101" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=2ms status=304 bytes=269 protocol=https
2022-07-26T23:54:30.585493+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/manifest.json" host=bloglazaustin.herokuapp.com request_id=74af37c2-3176-445b-8d37-2dd9f21c6374 fwd="75.66.230.101" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=1ms status=304 bytes=268 protocol=https2022-07-26T23:54:30.588690+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=bloglazaustin.herokuapp.com request_id=5506af5c-d6ec-427a-bdc5-c0ccbccaa4b6 fwd="75.66.230.101" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=1ms status=304 bytes=269 protocol=https  
2022-07-26T23:54:30.617991+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/categories" host=bloglazaustin.herokuapp.com request_id=77bd415c-1910-4193-92b3-3f77e20ef5fc fwd="75.66.230.101" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=1ms status=304 bytes=269 protocol=https   
2022-07-26T23:55:24.000000+00:00 app[api]: Build started by user lazaustin94@gmail.com
2022-07-26T23:56:21.078809+00:00 app[api]: Deploy df31ac24 by user lazaustin94@gmail.com
2022-07-26T23:56:21.078809+00:00 app[api]: Release v34 created by user lazaustin94@gmail.com
2022-07-26T23:56:23.000000+00:00 app[api]: Build succeeded
2022-07-26T23:56:26.717628+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Restarting
2022-07-26T23:56:26.731758+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from up to starting
2022-07-26T23:56:27.319192+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Stopping all processes with SIGTERM
2022-07-26T23:56:27.478388+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 143
2022-07-26T23:56:33.556717+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `npm start`
2022-07-26T23:56:35.172015+00:00 app[web.1]:
2022-07-26T23:56:35.172025+00:00 app[web.1]: > laz-blog@1.0.0 start
2022-07-26T23:56:35.172026+00:00 app[web.1]: > nodemon index.js
2022-07-26T23:56:35.172026+00:00 app[web.1]:
2022-07-26T23:56:35.293008+00:00 app[web.1]: [nodemon] 2.0.7
2022-07-26T23:56:35.293636+00:00 app[web.1]: [nodemon] to restart at any time, enter `rs`
2022-07-26T23:56:35.293956+00:00 app[web.1]: [nodemon] watching path(s): *.*
2022-07-26T23:56:35.293991+00:00 app[web.1]: [nodemon] watching extensions: js,mjs,json
2022-07-26T23:56:35.294290+00:00 app[web.1]: [nodemon] starting `node index.js`
2022-07-26T23:56:35.676830+00:00 app[web.1]: Connected to MongoDB
2022-07-26T23:56:35.679285+00:00 app[web.1]: Backend is running.
2022-07-26T23:56:35.710452+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to up
2022-07-26T23:56:51.250305+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/" host=bloglazaustin.herokuapp.com request_id=05b61cd0-4f8b-41a3-97a5-09edc736a52b fwd="75.66.230.101" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=7ms status=200 bytes=1388 protocol=https
2022-07-26T23:56:51.388895+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/static/js/main.c018063c.js" host=bloglazaustin.herokuapp.com request_id=4631b8c8-2cc9-43cf-83e8-e1add24e8fa3 fwd="75.66.230.101" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=3ms status=200 bytes=204076 protocol=https
2022-07-26T23:56:51.392767+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/static/css/main.8101a4de.css" host=bloglazaustin.herokuapp.com request_id=b7e33062-636f-41ae-8a73-c34ab7609908 fwd="75.66.230.101" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=2ms status=200 bytes=15628 protocol=https
2022-07-26T23:56:51.785403+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/static/media/lazPng1.90669477e0ea598ca37d.png" host=bloglazaustin.herokuapp.com request_id=9b1b5dbe-05f2-48a6-8f63-66e7458b86f6 fwd="75.66.230.101" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=2ms status=200 bytes=212690 protocol=https
2022-07-26T23:56:51.799386+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/static/media/lazProf.77a7e469645a5f9fb12b.jpg" host=bloglazaustin.herokuapp.com request_id=7b004902-0371-4f30-a7db-4b065951fae8 fwd="75.66.230.101" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=11ms status=200 bytes=1142755 protocol=https
2022-07-26T23:56:51.949744+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/categories" host=bloglazaustin.herokuapp.com request_id=cc51c0a1-cece-4e92-b3b2-22bfe450e5b2 fwd="75.66.230.101" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=3ms status=200 bytes=1388 protocol=https  
2022-07-26T23:56:51.951297+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/manifest.json" host=bloglazaustin.herokuapp.com request_id=4332f05c-238f-42a5-9e13-5fc41896cf71 fwd="75.66.230.101" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=4ms status=200 bytes=373 protocol=https2022-07-26T23:56:51.951469+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/posts" host=bloglazaustin.herokuapp.com request_id=110fad1b-f878-40c9-90fa-4751dcf94d77 fwd="75.66.230.101" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=5ms status=200 bytes=1388 protocol=https       
2022-07-26T23:56:51.953621+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=bloglazaustin.herokuapp.com request_id=e98f7003-9e64-4440-930f-ce04f5b8a1d3 fwd="75.66.230.101" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=5ms status=200 bytes=1388 protocol=https
2022-07-26T23:56:52.016333+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/categories" host=bloglazaustin.herokuapp.com request_id=02f31e31-eb23-40cc-8b61-2bf9c8b25f4d fwd="75.66.230.101" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=1ms status=304 bytes=269 protocol=https   
2022-07-27T00:11:18.671291+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/" host=bloglazaustin.herokuapp.com request_id=0f73d7e6-a9b5-436e-bfd3-64d5a9c6642e fwd="75.66.230.101" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=1ms status=304 bytes=269 protocol=https
2022-07-27T00:11:18.804654+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/static/css/main.8101a4de.css" host=bloglazaustin.herokuapp.com request_id=08693ca4-4986-4678-82a7-cf02555a3a69 fwd="75.66.230.101" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=2ms status=200 bytes=15628 protocol=https
2022-07-27T00:11:18.805181+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/static/js/main.c018063c.js" host=bloglazaustin.herokuapp.com request_id=caf8652c-d797-4943-9c4d-dc5b48c3b16c fwd="75.66.230.101" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=5ms status=200 bytes=204076 protocol=https
2022-07-27T00:11:19.235269+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/static/media/lazProf.77a7e469645a5f9fb12b.jpg" host=bloglazaustin.herokuapp.com request_id=ce5f20d9-94d9-4212-8059-88752b0680ab fwd="75.66.230.101" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=1ms status=304 bytes=272 protocol=https
2022-07-27T00:11:19.236183+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/static/media/lazPng1.90669477e0ea598ca37d.png" host=bloglazaustin.herokuapp.com request_id=0483ff5d-ea3e-4165-9a8f-d89912606116 fwd="75.66.230.101" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=2ms status=304 bytes=271 protocol=https
2022-07-27T00:11:19.289911+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=bloglazaustin.herokuapp.com request_id=f28a0aae-76c2-467e-a4c4-da4387157800 fwd="75.66.230.101" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=1ms status=304 bytes=269 protocol=https
2022-07-27T00:11:19.295618+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/categories" host=bloglazaustin.herokuapp.com request_id=0a18a876-9cfd-4eca-b615-c6ef3f32c6df fwd="75.66.230.101" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=1ms status=304 bytes=269 protocol=https   
2022-07-27T00:11:19.348238+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/posts" host=bloglazaustin.herokuapp.com request_id=cf8c818a-1d5c-403a-8f72-0a3feb2c36b7 fwd="75.66.230.101" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=1ms status=304 bytes=269 protocol=https        
2022-07-27T00:11:19.355391+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/categories" host=bloglazaustin.herokuapp.com request_id=ebf4f2b1-e4e4-49b6-8eaa-fd5d60d13907 fwd="75.66.230.101" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=1ms status=304 bytes=269 protocol=https   
2022-07-27T00:11:19.407917+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/manifest.json" host=bloglazaustin.herokuapp.com request_id=717047c3-97d5-472a-9911-b33a1b73b553 fwd="75.66.230.101" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=1ms status=304 bytes=268 protocol=https2022-07-27T00:11:22.248438+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/" host=bloglazaustin.herokuapp.com request_id=514a47ee-6c86-4ed8-a6be-c0d38abb6b3f fwd="75.66.230.101" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=1ms status=304 bytes=269 protocol=https
2022-07-27T00:11:22.365576+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/static/js/main.c018063c.js" host=bloglazaustin.herokuapp.com request_id=d63ccd7f-985e-4299-92ed-acded350a1c1 fwd="75.66.230.101" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=1ms status=304 bytes=271 protocol=https
2022-07-27T00:11:22.370109+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/static/css/main.8101a4de.css" host=bloglazaustin.herokuapp.com request_id=ef51cadb-da2d-4026-9622-f5fd7c7bb406 fwd="75.66.230.101" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=1ms status=304 bytes=270 protocol=https
2022-07-27T00:11:22.467675+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/static/media/lazPng1.90669477e0ea598ca37d.png" host=bloglazaustin.herokuapp.com request_id=0a5ce003-9adb-405f-b237-43edeb2ae291 fwd="75.66.230.101" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=1ms status=304 bytes=271 protocol=https
2022-07-27T00:11:22.486568+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/static/media/lazProf.77a7e469645a5f9fb12b.jpg" host=bloglazaustin.herokuapp.com request_id=050f94e0-1c40-4f17-b877-8536af01c386 fwd="75.66.230.101" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=1ms status=304 bytes=272 protocol=https
2022-07-27T00:11:22.488498+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=bloglazaustin.herokuapp.com request_id=6acd6691-69e0-42a8-af4b-c38fddc69dce fwd="75.66.230.101" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=2ms status=304 bytes=269 protocol=https  
2022-07-27T00:11:22.492732+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/categories" host=bloglazaustin.herokuapp.com request_id=039b0c5d-7b07-4cda-b7ef-049cc95fb184 fwd="75.66.230.101" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=1ms status=304 bytes=269 protocol=https   
2022-07-27T00:11:22.500030+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/posts" host=bloglazaustin.herokuapp.com request_id=626504a2-a1f0-4494-a644-6a8bb3211de0 fwd="75.66.230.101" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=1ms status=304 bytes=269 protocol=https        
2022-07-27T00:11:22.525796+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/manifest.json" host=bloglazaustin.herokuapp.com request_id=109ab65d-1676-41de-b1eb-4c48fc86d792 fwd="75.66.230.101" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=1ms status=304 bytes=268 protocol=https2022-07-27T00:11:22.561909+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/categories" host=bloglazaustin.herokuapp.com request_id=80848aa2-908e-451d-9321-a14afc901aba fwd="75.66.230.101" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=1ms status=304 bytes=269 protocol=https   
2022-07-27T00:31:02.439598+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/static/css/main.8101a4de.css" host=bloglazaustin.herokuapp.com request_id=d4303f33-eed9-4849-9b1c-f500fdf505d2 fwd="75.66.230.101" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=1ms status=304 bytes=270 protocol=https
2022-07-27T00:31:02.441506+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/manifest.json" host=bloglazaustin.herokuapp.com request_id=fab18628-b5dc-4f51-af5d-90442ca0d1f8 fwd="75.66.230.101" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=1ms status=304 bytes=268 protocol=https2022-07-27T00:31:02.452725+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/static/js/main.c018063c.js.map" host=bloglazaustin.herokuapp.com request_id=80c6be39-c8ad-42ea-aec7-d8a61272d85e fwd="75.66.230.101" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=12ms status=200 bytes=595475 protocol=https
2022-07-27T00:31:02.506392+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/static/css/main.8101a4de.css.map" host=bloglazaustin.herokuapp.com request_id=ff8c1e16-a5dc-4127-9de2-7007cad8f197 fwd="75.66.230.101" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=1ms status=200 bytes=6345 protocol=https
```

Here is my backend index.js file

```
const express = require("express");
const dotenv = require("dotenv");
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const authRoute = require("./routes/auth");
const userRoute = require("./routes/users");
const postRoute = require("./routes/posts");
const categoryRoute = require("./routes/categories");
const multer = require("multer");
const path = require("path");
const cors = require("cors");
const app = express();
app.use(cors());

dotenv.config();
app.use(express.json());
app.use("/images", express.static(path.join(__dirname, "/images")));

mongoose
  .connect(process.env.MONGO_URL, {
    useNewUrlParser: true,
    useUnifiedTopology: true,
    useCreateIndex: true,
    useFindAndModify:true
  })
  .then(console.log("Connected to MongoDB"))
  .catch((err) => console.log(err));

const storage = multer.diskStorage({
  destination: (req, file, cb) => {
    cb(null, "images");
  },
  filename: (req, file, cb) => {
    cb(null, req.body.name);
  },
});

const upload = multer({ storage: storage });
app.post("/api/upload", upload.single("file"), (req, res) => {
  res.status(200).json("File has been uploaded");
});

app.use("/api/auth", authRoute);
app.use("/api/users", userRoute);
app.use("/api/posts", postRoute);
app.use("/api/categories", categoryRoute);

//Serve Front End
if (process.env.NODE_ENV === "production") {

  app.use(express.static('client/build'))  // set static folder 
  
  app.get('*', (req, res)=> {     
    res.sendFile(path.resolve(__dirname, 'client', 'build',         
                  'index.html' )); 
  })
}

app.listen(process.env.PORT || 5000, () => {
  console.log("Backend is running.");
});
```

My outer api `package.json` scripts

```
"scripts": {
    "start": "nodemon index.js",
    "heroku-postbuild":"NPM_CONFIG_PRODUCTION=false npm install --prefix client && npm run build --prefix client"
  },
```

My inner client scripts

```
"scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
```

//Edit
Added complete browser data

```
{
    "data": "<!doctype html><html lang=\"en\"><head><meta charset=\"utf-8\"/><link rel=\"icon\" href=\"/favicon.ico\"/><meta name=\"viewport\" content=\"width=device-width,initial-scale=1\"/><meta name=\"theme-color\" content=\"#000000\"/><meta name=\"description\" content=\"Web site created using create-react-app\"/><link rel=\"apple-touch-icon\" href=\"/logo192.png\"/><link rel=\"manifest\" href=\"/manifest.json\"/><link href=\"https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Josefin+Sans:wght@100;200;300;400;500;600;700&family=Lora:ital@0;1&family=Varela&family=Varela+Round&display=swap\" rel=\"stylesheet\"><link rel=\"stylesheet\" href=\"https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.15.3/css/all.min.css\" integrity=\"sha512-iBBXm8fW90+nuLcSKlbmrPcLa0OT92xO1BIsZ+ywDWZCvqsWgccV3gFoRBv0z+8dLJgyAHIhR35VZc2oM/gI1w==\" crossorigin=\"anonymous\"/><title>React App</title><script defer=\"defer\" src=\"/static/js/main.c018063c.js\"></script><link href=\"/static/css/main.8101a4de.css\" rel=\"stylesheet\"></head><body><noscript>You need to enable JavaScript to run this app.</noscript><div id=\"root\"></div></body></html>",
    "status": 200,
    "statusText": "OK",
    "headers": {
        "accept-ranges": "bytes",
        "access-control-allow-origin": "*",
        "cache-control": "public, max-age=0",
        "content-length": "1067",
        "content-type": "text/html; charset=UTF-8",
        "date": "Wed, 27 Jul 2022 02:10:49 GMT",
        "etag": "W/\"42b-1823cf06a08\"",
        "last-modified": "Tue, 26 Jul 2022 23:56:05 GMT",
        "server": "Cowboy",
        "via": "1.1 vegur",
        "x-powered-by": "Express"
    },
    "config": {
        "transitional": {
            "silentJSONParsing": true,
            "forcedJSONParsing": true,
            "clarifyTimeoutError": false
        },
        "transformRequest": [
            null
        ],
        "transformResponse": [
            null
        ],
        "timeout": 0,
        "xsrfCookieName": "XSRF-TOKEN",
        "xsrfHeaderName": "X-XSRF-TOKEN",
        "maxContentLength": -1,
        "maxBodyLength": -1,
        "env": {
            "FormData": null
        },
        "headers": {
            "Accept": "application/json, text/plain, */*"
        },
        "method": "get",
        "url": "/posts"
    },
    "request": {}
}
```

// Edit Added more about the TypeError. It shows this for every component that has a .map function. But .map works just fine locally and from what i've researched this is a common issue when deploying mern to heroku.

```
Uncaught TypeError: t.map is not a function
    at ce (Posts.jsx:8:18)
    at Eo (react-dom.production.min.js:167:137)
    at _i (react-dom.production.min.js:197:258)
    at Su (react-dom.production.min.js:292:88)
    at bs (react-dom.production.min.js:280:389)
    at gs (react-dom.production.min.js:280:320)
    at vs (react-dom.production.min.js:280:180)
    at ls (react-dom.production.min.js:271:88)
    at as (react-dom.production.min.js:268:429)
    at k (scheduler.production.min.js:13:203)
```

Comment: Show all error from browser, please

Comment: Added as much as I could without going over the character limit. If anyone wants more, it's pretty quick to click on the link and open dev tools.

Comment: I refer to show error browser when is `Uncaught TypeError: n.map is not a function`

Comment: Added. It shows the above for <Posts />, <Sidebar /> <Navbar /> etc. Every component with a .map function

Comment: well,  your error is in `Posts.jsx`, your variable wich is using a `map function` is not an array

Comment: I just fixed it a few hours ago. It's not the map function. Map works fine locally and on heroku after I fixed the axios paths. There are a million similar questions on here with the same problem and everybody had the same response about it not being an array. It's jsx and works a little different.

Comment: What was the error?

Comment: My express paths were "/api/about" for example while the axios paths on the front end were missing the /api part. Most people I've seen do that but idk why because mistakes like this happen